# Insert dynamically in the placeholders after writing in the text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to insert data onto placeholders after I write in a text box. I found an alternative solution with Drop-down select:

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

How to modify it if I want to use with `Form::text('foo')` and start to start search from mysql table immidiately?

Comment: A: Replace the `<select>` with an text input and remove `intval()` to be replaced with a prepared statement.

Comment: Do you really mean to output a complete HTML document (with html, head, body tags etc...) in the div `txtHint`?

Comment: along with a case insensitive function; you have enough information to try something now ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- and Magnus, I will try these informations :) What's the protocoll here on SO, when the answer comes from a comment? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `<select>` with a text input and remove `intval()` and replaced with a prepared statement, since you don't want to be victim to an SQL injection.

Rererences:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You can also use a case insensitive search method/function, and there are a few ways to go about this.

Using MySQL's LIKE function:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Or a pattern match:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Or a `WHERE` clause:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html

Depending on the search criteria.